# Non-vanishing vector field on $SO(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

The only fact I know about non-vanishing vector field is sphere has non-vanishing vector field if and only if it has odd dimension. Now I see a problem in a book which ask to show $SO(n)$ has non-vanishing vector field. Actually I know nothing about such linear group, could someone help?

By the way, is there any similar statement, i.e. for some particular space, we know there exists non-vanishing vector field.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is any matrix Lie subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ is a (nonzero) element of the corresponding lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. there is a differentiable path $x:[0,1]\to G$ with $x(0)=\mathrm{Id}$ and $x'(0)=X$. Then for any $g\in G$ we can say $gX$ is a tangent vector at $g$ (it is $gx(t)$ differentiated at $t=0$), and so the map $g\mapsto gX$ is a nonvanishing vector field on $G$.

Comment: I  am sorry, I am confused what is $X$, it seems to me that $X$ is just a tangent vector, so why it is non vanishing?

Comment: @user330928 $X$ is a *nonzero* tangent vector, and so $gX$ is nonzero for all $g\in G$, i.e. the vector field $g\mapsto gX$ is nonvanishing.